# Bootstrap css column width between col-sm-2 and col-sm-1

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and in certain div i am usign col-sm-2 clas which has a width of 16.6667%. In this width I am seeing my elements quite big.

I also tried with col-sm-1 but this time the elements are too small.

I tried changing this percentage in firebug and I found my perfect percentage 12.5%;

Is there any way to create a col-sm-1_5 class keeping the website being responsive (only should affect to sm environment)?

I tried creating the following class but, of course, this would affect to all the devices (xs,md,lg) not only to sm:

```
.col-sm-1-5 {
    width: 12.5%;
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try Nested Columns... [Nested Columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting)

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
 <div class="col-sm-4">1/3 *2</div>
 <div class="col-sm-8">2/3 *2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: change the inner divs classes with "col-sm-6"